# why assigned rococo parachain slots in parathread?

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, rococo, slot

My assigned slots Id in rococo, it was listed in `parachain-overview` section but now it is in `Parathread` section with leases `456 - 460`. What is the meaning of this? Someone please explain.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a parachain lease ends, it becomes a parathread, and its existing state root and Wasm stays on the relay chain. There was probably something wrong with your onboarding.

After re-onboard it, looks it appears as a parachain: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rpc.polkadot.io#/parachains